# Network detecting of Ionic 2 not working correctly

Tags: ionic2, wifi, offline

I made function that detect the network status and every thing works fine when I test this function on browser or ionic view app.

**My problem happened when I installed my app on my android device, I turned-off my wifi but nothing happens.**

Here is my code:

```
constructor(...){
    platform.ready().then(() => {
         ...
         this.checkConnection();
    })
}

checkConnection(){
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        //this.displayNetworkUpdate(data.type);
        if(this.isOffline==true){
            this.isOffline=false;
            this.toast.dismiss();
        }
    }, error => console.error(error)); 
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        //this.displayNetworkUpdate(data.type);
        if(this.isOffline==false){
            this.isOffline=true;
            this.toast= this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'No Internet connection. Make sure that Wi-Fi or Cellular mobile data is turned on, then continue using the application.',
                duration: 99999999999
            });
            this.toast.present();
        }
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that those Observables are for changes in state.  See this solution I created.

**providers/LastKnownNetworkState.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Network} from '@ionic-native/network';


@Injectable()
export class LastKnownNetworkState {
  online: boolean;

  constructor(private network: Network) {
    // can get the initial state.
    this.online = navigator.onLine;


    // these will capture change in state
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.online = false;
    });
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.online = true;
    });

  }

  isOnline(): boolean {
    return this.online;
  }

}
```